# "When a new email arrives (V3)" using different email address compared to the creator of the flow, will not get triggered

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform, exchange, exchange-online

I have a service account named SharePointDev and a service account named SharePointDevTest. now using the SharePointDev account i created a flow >> and i defined the SharePointDevTest inside the To field. but when an email get sent to SharePointDevTest the trigger will never get triggered.. any advice?

[image]

while if i create a flow using the SharePointDev and i also defined the To field to be SharePointDev the trigger will get executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't use flow to listen (spy) on another user's mailbox.

However, the flow will probably listen to the inbox that is for the account that is configured in your trigger's connection.

If you create a connection to the SharePointDevTest account from within your flow, that might work.

[image: Example]